# Google Sheets - match 2 conditions with REGEX, date and a word

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to match one word and one date based on data from two cells in Google Sheets.

[image]

What I want to say is: If A1 matches `Apple` and B2 is `17.05.2019` then return `MAY FRUIT`

I am using `REGEX` as sometimes the text in A1 will be a partial match.

I am trying variations of this but to no avail:

```
=AND (REGEXMATCH(A1,"Apple"),(REGEXMATCH(A1,"Apple"),"MAY FRUIT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula must be `IF`, not `AND`.

> If A1 matches "Apple" and B2 is "17.05.2019" then return "MAY FRUIT"

```vb
=IF(AND(REGEXMATCH(A1, "Apple"), B2="17.05.2019"), "MAY FRUIT", "")
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it could be also written ditching `AND` like:

```
=IF((REGEXMATCH(A1, "Apple"))*(B1="17.05.2019"), "MAY FRUIT", )
```

[image: 0]

and further expanded into `ARRAYFORMULA` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "Apple"))*(B1:B="17.05.2019"), "MAY FRUIT", ))
```

[image: 0]

however, it would be recommended to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A1:A), "apple"))*
                 (MONTH(B1:B)=5)*
                 (DAY(B1:B)=17), "MAY FRUIT", ))
```

[image: 0]